# Listing pod exec sessions in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've got a cassandra pod in which I can see several cqlsh sessions running. Since this is a shared dev kubernetes cluster, I figure it must be some devs running `kubectl exec` into the pod to run some queries.

My question is then if there is a way to list and get any information on all the `exec`s for a given pod.

Comment: exec yourself into that pod and run `ps` or `top` or sth similar?

Comment: @MarianTheisen That's exactly what I did to find out that there were other execs, but  I cannot see any information on e.g. the IP or the role used to exec into the pod. I also cannot exclude that some of the processes are actually spun up by another process within the pod.

Comment: ah i see, then maybe you want to look into your audit logs if set up. found this https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/rvr9ez/how_to_log_the_kubectl_exec_event/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link shared by @Marian Theisen

You would want to set up [API auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) on the pod/exec endpoint.

Kubernetes auditing provides a security-relevant, chronological set of records documenting the sequence of actions in a cluster. The cluster audits the activities generated by users, by applications that use the Kubernetes API, and by the control plane itself.

Also refer to this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/get-shell-running-container/) for more information.